# displays detailed data from recyclerview, but the String name is the same

Tags: android

displays detailed data from recyclerview, but the String name is the same, I want to display the nameProduct data, but because in the public static final String Contans String KEY_NAME_PRODUCT = "name"; and public static final String KEY_NAME_MERCHNAT = "name"; has the same json field, name. therefore if I take the detailed data the name of the product displayed is the merchant's name. so I failed to display the product name, while in Recylerview the product name displays as it should. how can I differentiate between product name and merchant name

myinten from Recycler

```
   private void initDataIntent(final List<ResultItem> detaiList){
        listAllProduct.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(mContext, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                         String id = detaiList.get(position).getId();
                         String id_currency = detaiList.get(position).getCurrency().getId();
                         String id_product_category = detaiList.get(position).getCategory().getId();
                         String nameProduct = detaiList.get(position).getName();
                         String description = detaiList.get(position).getDescription();
                         String stock = detaiList.get(position).getStock();
                         String price_capital = detaiList.get(position).getPriceCapital();
                         String price_sale = detaiList.get(position).getPriceSale();
                         String condition = detaiList.get(position).getCondition();
                         String imageProduct = detaiList.get(position).getImage();
                         String weight_value = detaiList.get(position).getMetadata().getWeightValue();
                         String weight = detaiList.get(position).getMetadata().getWeight();
                         String nameMerchant = detaiList.get(position).getMerchant().getName();
                         //String city = detaiList.get(position).getMerchant().getCity();


                        Intent detailproduct = new Intent(mContext, DetailProduct.class);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_ID, id);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_ID_PRODUCT_CATEGORY, id_product_category);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_ID_CURRENCY, id_currency);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_NAME_PRODUCT, nameProduct);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_PRICE_CAPITAL, price_capital);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_PRICE_SALE, price_sale);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_DESCRIPTIOM, description);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_STOCK, stock);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_CONDITION, condition);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_IMAGE, imageProduct);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_WEIGHT_VALUE, weight_value);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_WEIGHT, weight);
                        detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_NAME_MERCHNAT, nameMerchant);
                        ///detailproduct.putExtra(Constans.KEY_CITY_MERCHANT, city);
                        startActivity(detailproduct);
                    }
                }));
    }
```

Constans.java

```
public class Constans {

    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_ID_PRODUCT_CATEGORY = "id_product_category";
    public static final String KEY_ID_CURRENCY = "id_currency";
    public static final String KEY_NAME_PRODUCT = "name";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE_CAPITAL = "price_capital";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE_SALE = "price_sale";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTIOM = "description";
    public static final String KEY_CONDITION = "condition";
    public static final String KEY_STOCK = "stock";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String KEY_WEIGHT_VALUE = "weight_value";
    public static final String KEY_WEIGHT= "weight";
    public static final String KEY_NAME_MERCHNAT = "name";
    public static final String KEY_CITY_MERCHANT = "city";

}
```

detail.java

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
id = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_ID);
id_currency = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_ID_CURRENCY);
id_product_category = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_ID_PRODUCT_CATEGORY);
nameProduct = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_NAME_PRODUCT);

///convert String to Rupiah Curerncy
Locale localeID = new Locale("in", "ID");
NumberFormat formatRupiah = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(localeID);
int price_capital = (Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_PRICE_CAPITAL)));
int price_sale = (Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_PRICE_SALE)));

//price_capital = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_PRICE_CAPITAL);
///price_sale = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_PRICE_SALE);
description = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_DESCRIPTIOM);
condition = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_CONDITION);
stock = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_STOCK);
imageProduct = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_IMAGE);
weight_value = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_WEIGHT_VALUE);
weight = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_WEIGHT);
nameMerchant = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_NAME_MERCHNAT);
///city = intent.getStringExtra(Constans.KEY_CITY_MERCHANT);




txt_id.setText(id);
txt_id_product_category.setText(id_currency);
txt_id_currency.setText(id_product_category);
txt_name_product.setText(nameProduct);
txt_price_capital.setText(formatRupiah.format(price_capital));
txt_price_sale.setText(formatRupiah.format(price_sale));
///txt_description.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(getIntent().getStringExtra("description"))), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
txt_description.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, description, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
txt_condition.setText(condition);
txt_stock.setText(stock);
///image.setImageResource(imageproduct);

Glide.with(DetailProduct.this)
        .load(imageProduct)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
        .error(R.drawable.no_image)
        .into(imageView);

txt_weight_value.setText(weight_value+weight);
txt_name_merchant.setText(nameMerchant);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent's extras are stored as a map, so it must have unique names.

To get it, just differentiate values in `Constants`:

```
public static final String KEY_NAME_PRODUCT = "name_product";
public static final String KEY_NAME_MERCHNAT = "name_merchnat";
```